# Magento2 - Any way to auto check a multiselect component?

Tags: magento, magento2, multi-select, uicomponents

Using ui-component

```
        <field name="interest" formElement="multiselect">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">
                    \Model\InterestOptions
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Interest</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

And the source of my list:

```
class InterestOptions implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

        return [
            'option1' => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 'option1'
            ],
            'option2' => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 'option2'
            ]
    }
}
```

I would like to make some value checked before loading the page.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a default value like this:

```xml
        <field name="interest" formElement="multiselect">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="object">
                        \Model\InterestOptions
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">
                    \Model\InterestOptions
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Interest</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

InterestOptions need to implement Magento\Framework\Data\ValueSourceInterface where getValue($name) return the default values

```php
class InterestOptions implements OptionSourceInterface, ValueSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

        return [
            'option1' => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 'option1'
            ],
            'option2' => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 'option2'
            ]
    }
    
    public function getValue($name)
    {
        return ["option2"];
    }
}
```